# Group by using 2 columns and if the time difference between the rows of third column is less than 2 seconds python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data in my csv

```
A_PERSON,B_PERSON,DATE_TIME,DURATION
190,390,'2020-04-20 12:44:36',323
282,811,'2020-04-06 11:12:24',25
495,414,'2020-04-20 11:22:13',11
827,158,'2020-04-30 13:27:22',22
827,158,'2020-04-30 13:27:44',15
```

I am trying to group rows with same `A_PERSON,B_PERSON` and if the difference between `DATE_TIME + DURATION` of one row and `DATE_TIME` of another row is less than 2 seconds. For example in the last 2 rows I have same `A_PERSON,B_PERSON` and the difference between `DATE_TIME of second last row + DURATION of second last row` and `DATE_TIME of last rows` is less than 2 seconds so only the last row should be merged and all other rows will be displayed as it is.

**Desired Output**

```
A_PERSON,B_PERSON,DATE_TIME,DURATION
190,390,'2020-04-20 12:44:36',323
282,811,'2020-04-06 11:12:24',25
495,414,'2020-04-20 11:22:13',11
827,158,'2020-04-30 13:27:22',37
```

Till now I have tried this

```
def merger(dataframe:pd.core.frame.DataFrame)->pd.core.frame.DataFrame:
    dataframe['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['DATE_TIME'])
    dataframe['epoch'] = (dataframe['DATE_TIME'] - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()
    mask = dataframe[((dataframe['epoch']) < dataframe['epoch'] + 1 + dataframe['DURATION'])]
    grouped = mask.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON"]).sum("DURATION")
    print(grouped)
    return grouped
```

In this code `group by` on the `A_PERSON,B_PERSON` is working but the `where mask` is not working

**Sample 2**

```
A_PERSON,B_PERSON,DATE_TIME,DURATION
441785807190,4299330390,'2020-04-20 12:44:36',323
441785808282,4238900811,'2020-04-06 11:12:24',25
14244012495,3104405414,'2020-04-20 11:22:13',11
96897940827,3139578158,'2020-04-30 13:27:02',32
96897940827,3139578158,'2020-04-30 13:27:34',16
```

**Desired output for sample 2**

```
A_PERSON,B_PERSON,DATE_TIME,DURATION
441785807190,4299330390,'2020-04-20 12:44:36',323
441785808282,4238900811,'2020-04-06 11:12:24',25
14244012495,3104405414,'2020-04-20 11:22:13',11
96897940827,3139578158,'2020-04-30 13:27:02',48
```

**Sample 3**

```
A_PERSON,B_PERSON,DATE_TIME,DURATION
441785807190,4299330390,'2020-04-20 12:44:36',323
96897940827,3139578158,'2020-04-30 13:27:00',33
441785808282,4238900811,'2020-04-06 11:12:24',25
14244012495,3104405414,'2020-04-20 11:22:13',11
96897940827,3139578158,'2020-04-30 13:27:34',16
```

**Desired output for sample 3**

```
A_PERSON,B_PERSON,DATE_TIME,DURATION
441785807190,4299330390,'2020-04-20 12:44:36',323
96897940827,3139578158,'2020-04-30 13:27:00',49
441785808282,4238900811,'2020-04-06 11:12:24',25
14244012495,3104405414,'2020-04-20 11:22:13',11
```

Comment: Now it is `13:27:59 - 13:27:44 = 15 seconds`

Comment: That Difference can be any second i have to match to `time + duration` of one row with the `time` of other rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sample data is difference `5` seconds in last group (`13:27:59 - 13:27:54 = 5seconds`).

Solution is add `DURATION` in seconds to new column `add` and per groups get differencies by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with compare invert condition for greater like `N` with cumulative sum for new group column, last aggregate `first` and `sum`:

```
N = 5
dataframe['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['DATE_TIME'])

dataframe['add'] = dataframe['DATE_TIME'] + pd.to_timedelta(dataframe['DURATION'],unit='s')
f = lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds().gt(N).cumsum()
dataframe['g'] =  dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON"])['add'].transform(f)
print (dataframe)
   A_PERSON  B_PERSON           DATE_TIME  DURATION                 add  g
0       190       390 2020-04-20 12:44:36       323 2020-04-20 12:49:59  0
1       282       811 2020-04-06 11:12:24        25 2020-04-06 11:12:49  0
2       495       414 2020-04-20 11:22:13        11 2020-04-20 11:22:24  0
3       827       158 2020-04-30 13:27:32        22 2020-04-30 13:27:54  0
4       827       158 2020-04-30 13:27:44        15 2020-04-30 13:27:59  0

dataframe = (dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON", 'g'])
                      .agg({'DATE_TIME':'first', 'DURATION':'sum'})
                      .droplevel(-1)
                      .reset_index())

print (dataframe)
   A_PERSON  B_PERSON           DATE_TIME  DURATION
0       190       390 2020-04-20 12:44:36       323
1       282       811 2020-04-06 11:12:24        25
2       495       414 2020-04-20 11:22:13        11
3       827       158 2020-04-30 13:27:32        37
```

If need compare `add` shifted per groups by `DATE_TIME` column solution (with new data) is:

```
N = 2

dataframe['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['DATE_TIME'])

dataframe['add'] = dataframe['DATE_TIME'] + pd.to_timedelta(dataframe['DURATION'],unit='s')
dataframe['diff'] = dataframe['DATE_TIME'].sub(dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON"])['add'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().gt(N)

dataframe['g'] = dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON"])['diff'].cumsum()
print (dataframe)
   A_PERSON  B_PERSON           DATE_TIME  DURATION                 add  \
0       190       390 2020-04-20 12:44:36       323 2020-04-20 12:49:59   
1       282       811 2020-04-06 11:12:24        25 2020-04-06 11:12:49   
2       495       414 2020-04-20 11:22:13        11 2020-04-20 11:22:24   
3       827       158 2020-04-30 13:27:22        22 2020-04-30 13:27:44   
4       827       158 2020-04-30 13:27:44        15 2020-04-30 13:27:59   

    diff  g  
0  False  0  
1  False  0  
2  False  0  
3  False  0  
4  False  0
```

---

```
dataframe = (dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON", 'g'])
                      .agg({'DATE_TIME':'first', 'DURATION':'sum'})
                      .droplevel(-1)
                      .reset_index())

print (dataframe)
   A_PERSON  B_PERSON           DATE_TIME  DURATION
0       190       390 2020-04-20 12:44:36       323
1       282       811 2020-04-06 11:12:24        25
2       495       414 2020-04-20 11:22:13        11
3       827       158 2020-04-30 13:27:22        37
```

Tested 3rd sample:

```
N = 2

dataframe['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['DATE_TIME'])

dataframe['add'] = dataframe['DATE_TIME'] + pd.to_timedelta(dataframe['DURATION'],unit='s')
dataframe['diff'] = dataframe['DATE_TIME'].sub(dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON"])['add'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().gt(N)

dataframe['g'] = dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON"])['diff'].cumsum()
print (dataframe)
       A_PERSON    B_PERSON           DATE_TIME  DURATION                 add  \
0  441785807190  4299330390 2020-04-20 12:44:36       323 2020-04-20 12:49:59   
1   96897940827  3139578158 2020-04-30 13:27:00        33 2020-04-30 13:27:33   
2  441785808282  4238900811 2020-04-06 11:12:24        25 2020-04-06 11:12:49   
3   14244012495  3104405414 2020-04-20 11:22:13        11 2020-04-20 11:22:24   
4   96897940827  3139578158 2020-04-30 13:27:34        16 2020-04-30 13:27:50   

    diff  g  
0  False  0  
1  False  0  
2  False  0  
3  False  0  
4  False  0
```

---

```
dataframe = (dataframe.groupby(["A_PERSON", "B_PERSON", 'g'])
                      .agg({'DATE_TIME':'first', 'DURATION':'sum'})
                      .droplevel(-1)
                      .reset_index())

print (dataframe)
       A_PERSON    B_PERSON           DATE_TIME  DURATION
0   14244012495  3104405414 2020-04-20 11:22:13        11
1   96897940827  3139578158 2020-04-30 13:27:00        49
2  441785807190  4299330390 2020-04-20 12:44:36       323
3  441785808282  4238900811 2020-04-06 11:12:24        25
```

Comment: Haha, I didn't have time to type an answer 1h ago but I was sure you would come by :p Had the same logic in mind +1

Comment: Hi @jezrael thanks for your reply I was eagerly waiting for this answer. Your solution is working fine but there is an issue. I am not sure tha this N will be always 5 seconds

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - How is processing multiple rows per groups? If first difference is `2` second and another 10? Or if another is `1` second?

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - In another words if are 3 or more rows per groups?

Comment: @jezrael yes difference can be any seconds but i have to merge only those in which difference is less than 2 seconds

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - Now solution is for less like 5 seconds, for `2` change `N=2`

Comment: Hi I tried this but it is not working let me show you another data sample

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - Can you add to question? Because bad format in comments.

Comment: @jezrael added sample 2 in question

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - then use second solution in my answer.

Comment: @jezrael 2nd is also not working. I have attached another sample. Can you please check that. Thanks for helping

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - For me working corectly also 3rd sample

Comment: @ZunnurainBadar - added to answer.